# How do I show that an element is a primitive element in $GF(2^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\alpha$ have the property $\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1 = 0$. Is this a primitive element in $GF(2^3)$, generated by $p(x) = x^3 + x + 1$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: **Hint.** Order of $\alpha$ divides the order of $\mathbb F_8^\times$.

Answer (score -1):

Check that $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $F_2$ (otherwise, it would have a root in $F_2$, which would have to be either $0$ or $1$).

Thus, $F_2(\alpha)$ has degree 3 over $F_2$. Hence, $F_2(\alpha)$ has cardinality 8 and thus, $F_2(\alpha) \cong GF(2^3)$. Done.

Comment: That is not the question. "Primitive element" means an element of multiplicative order $7.$ Of course, any element other than $0$ and $1$ of $GF(8)$ has order $7.$

Comment: But, for example, $F_2(\alpha)=GF(2^4)$ does not mean $\alpha$ is a primitive element.

Comment: How would you show it in that case? I have a list of these problems, one is showing that $\alpha$, with the property $\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1 = 0$, is a primitive element in $GF(2^4)$. I asked for just one because they look pretty similar, but I don't know how to show this in the general case.

Comment: There are $15$ non-zero elements of $GF(2^4)$ and, since the multiplicative group is cyclic, the elements which are not generators are the elements of order $1,$ $3$, of $5.$ But that would means $\alpha-1=0,$ $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0,$ or $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0.$ @SomethingSomething

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.